# How to filter multiple JSON data with Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm having some hard time filtering multiple json datas, I need to know the `type` of each data and if the type corresponds to a fruit then print the element's `fields` key, see python example comments for a better explanation.

Here's what the JSON looks like :

```
#json.items()

{
  'type': 'apple', 
  'fields': {
    'protein': '18g', 
    'glucide': '3%', 
   }
},  
{
  'type': 'banana', 
  'fields': {
    'protein': '22g', 
    'glucide': '8%', 
  }
},
```

Here's what I tried to do :

```
for key, value in json.items(): #access json dict.
    if key == 'type':           #access 'type' key
        if value == 'apple':        #check the fruit
            if key == 'fields':        #ERROR !!! Now I need to access the 'fields' key datas of this same fruit. !!!
                print('What a good fruit, be careful on quantity!')
                print('more :' + value['protein'] + ', ' + value['glucid'])

        if value == 'banana':    #if not apple check for bananas
            print('One banana each two days keeps you healthy !')
            print('more:' + value['protein'] + ', ' + value['glucid'])
```

Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Comment: If what you posted is your entire json, then you have a list of dicts, not just a dict. You need 2 loops.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What I posted doesn't look anything like my json because it has too much datas, this one is simplified so it's more understandable, but the number of 'fruit' vary

Comment: So printing out `json` gives you a list of those dicts?

Comment: Your 1st and 3rd if will never be true at the same time.

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah I saw that, that was the reason why I was asking the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems to be a list of dicts.

You then check if keys `type` and `fields` exist in the dictionary before checking their value, like this:

```
for d in data: # d is a dict
    if 'type' in d and 'fields' in d:
        if d['type'] == 'apple':
            ... # some print statements

        elif d['type'] == 'banana':
            ... # some more print statements
```

Comment: This works ! For usage purpose is it possible to not specify each key in the if statement and loop for all the existing keys ?

Comment: @Lindow If you want to print unique statements for each item, I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: @Lindow If you have a common print statement and nothing else, you can drop the ifs and just print something like `print("{}s have {} of protein and {} glucide".format(d['type'], d['fields']['protein'], d['fields']['glucide']))`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your representation of the JSON, it appears that is actually a list, not a dictionary. So in order to iterate through it, you could try something like this:

```
for item in json:
    fields = item['fields']
    if item['type'] == 'banana':
        print('Bananas have {} of protein and {} glucide'.format(fields['protein'], fields['glucide']))
    elif item['type'] == 'apple':
        print('Apples have {} of protein and {} glucide'.format(fields['protein'], fields['glucide']))
```